# Linux error - physical memory corrupted?

Tags: linux, memory, corruption

Good Morning,
I have a problem on opensuse 11.3.

I developed a program that runs 24 hour /24 hour 360 day /360 day. I have installed this program in about 60 / 70 computers. In four of this computer I have a problem.

After a random time (10 minutes / 1 hour / 1 day) my program crashs and I aren't able to start it again. The error is always about one or more files corruption. The files corrupted are random, sometimes my libs, sometimes my executable file, sometimes kernel lib, sometimes system files, apache server, ssh server etc...

I thought that it was an hard-disk problem, i tried to replace it but the problem occurs again.
Now I think that it can be a memory problem, in fact, if I reboot the computer or I clean the cached memory ( http://www.hosting.com/support/linux/clear-memory-cache-on-linux-server ) my program restarts successfully (but, after a random time the problem occur again).

What do you think? 
What can I do to be more sure that is a memory problem?
I haven't a direct access to this computers, I can connect to this pc through ssh client (putty).

I tryed to use memtester program ( http://www.linuxarticles.org/2010/12/test-memory-using-memtester-in-linux/ ) but the memory seems to be ok.

Thanks

Comment: Without knowing what you mean by "file corruption" and how this is detected, along with the code, it is unlikely anybody can help you.